# slim template condition syntax with vue.js and elixir

Tags: vue.js, elixir, phoenix-framework, slim-lang

How can I combine a vuejs condition with a vuejs variable and an elixir variable?

```
<div v-if="vuevar || <%= @conn.assigns.elixirvar %>">
```

Comment: Does that `conn.assigns.elixirvar` return `true` or `false`?

Comment: It's a string actually, I was thinking on previously - elixirvar = @conn.assigns.elixirvar then in the condition v-if="vuevar || elixirvar.length > 0"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does that `conn.assigns.elixirvar` return `true` or `false`?
>
> It's a string actually.

If it is a string, you should quote it:

```html
<div v-if="vuevar || '<%= @conn.assigns.elixirvar %>'">
```

Othwerwise it will be printed as an identifier.

Answer (score 2):

While adding quotes like @acdcjunior suggested would work in simple cases, it'll break when your string itself contains quotes or other special characters. The proper way to do this is to encode the value using a JSON encoder and then output it:

```
<div v-if="vuevar || <%= Poison.encode!(@conn.assigns.elixirvar) %>">
```

This will now work with booleans, strings, numbers, arrays, objects; basically everything JSON supports.